# Does HttpContext.User.GetUserId always return an int using .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, claims

Will 'GetUserId()' always return an int?
My users can't get to this controller method anonymously, they have to be logged in and have a claims principal.

```
var id = HttpContext.User.GetUserId();

public static int GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    return int.Parse(user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
}
```

Why I ask.

If I have a null check below my call, is it unnecessary and useless?

```
var id = HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
if (user == null) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404));
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a method called GetUserId. Which runtime are you using? What is the datatype of User, a [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: The best I can find [`UserManager<TUser>.GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which says it returns "The User ID claim value, or null if the claim is not present."

Comment: you should work with claim, not a user.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is from an extension I made. I've updated my post above. But I think the question still applies, if my user has to be logged in to get to this call, won't it always return a value?

Comment: It depends on what authentication scheme you're using. It might or might not attach a claim with [the correct key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.nameidentifier?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0).